# Geofence API Worklight

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, geofencing, worklight-geolocation

I'm developing a `Worklight` Application that uses `Geofence API`s. everything is working on the Worklight web emulator but I dunno how to test this feature on a mobile device.

How can I test going inside a `Geofence` radius? can I emulate `GPS coordinates`?

Thanks,

Comment: Ideally, you should test with a smaller geo-fence which you can get into and get out of. If you're using Android, you have apps like Fake GPS which can provide a different GPS location apart from the place you're in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the emulation capabilities in Android (DDMS perspective when using the Eclipse ADT plugins), or in XCode (for iOS). Note that in Android, the timestamps used when manually giving data points start from midnight for the given date.
As mentioned by Srik in the comment above, there also exist additional applications which you can use to feed in mock geo locations (although you may need to turn on the Allow Mock Locations option in the developer settings area).